# Can you pass the ISTQB Exam with just reading the syllabus?

Tags: testing

I am in the process of revising for the ISTQB Foundation exam and was wondering if you can pass the exam just by reading the syllabus available on the ISTQB website? Or do I need to read a software testing book alongside the Syllabus??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question.

Comment: I would like advice, where is the best place to post this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , sure all exams questions focus on syllabus chapters and on words expression, you able to get more info from other sources to improve you knowledge but for exams syllabus